# DevExtreme Angular8 make widgets's message show my language

Tags: widget, locale, devextreme-angular

when use DevExtreme DataGrid,click the delete button,it shows a message,i want to reset the message language to another one - like Japanese or Russian.

my project is Angular8,at the top of app.module.ts,before @NgModule,
i set the language like this:

```
import xxxxxxxxx;

import {locale} from 'devextreme/localization';
locale(navigator.language);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    xxxxxxx
```

i use Chrome,the browser's language is set to Chinese,
but when i click delete button,
the message is remain English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the loadMessages to make a localization apply to a widget. There is an [online demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Localization/UsingIntl/Angular/Light/) that shows this approach in action.